# How to intercept / modify excape key functionality in Qt

Tags: qt

I am trying to fix a bug in a Qt app which I did not write.  The window changes the background color of the entire window to red and puts up some buttons, dialog boxes, etc.  When the escape key is pushed, the boxes and buttons go away, leaving an empty red screen.  The Cancel button does the right thing in returning to the previous window.  I think I need to somehow be notified of when the escape key is pushed, and then call the same function as the cancel pushbutton does.  Hopefully, I can limit the scope of this special action to when the problem window is up.  I am an experienced programmer but a complete Qt newbie.  This app is purely C++.  To my knowledge, it does not appear to use any QML.  I am still searching through the Qt online documentation, but any suggestions / examples are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to both. As mentioned in my question, I also searched through the Qt online documentation and found what seemed to be a viable solution in the documentation of QWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event).  Since I was already a bit down that road when I received your answer, I decided to continue, and solved it by overriding that function in my subwidget.
For background / edification, can anyone tell me in a Qt application "world sense" which of the two solutions is better, or in what situations @dabbler's event Filter solution would be superior to this one.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on your specific `Qt version` and setup of your application. That said, I'll take a shot at helping. In the class where you're trying to intercept the escape key press, assuming it's inheriting `QObject`, simply override the virtual function `eventFilter`. Inside your overridden instance of `eventFilter`, check that the `QEvent` type is a `QEvent::KeyPress`, and then check whether the key of that `KeyPress` is the escape key, and handle as needed.

Be sure that you pass the event out of your function, else you'll see your overridden function eat all events. If you explicitly want the event to be "eaten", simply do not return it from your function. For specifics and examples, check out documentation of `QObject::eventFilter()`.